# PrimeFaces RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update() not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I use dialog framework of :

> http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dialogFrameworkData.jsf

I create a file view_test.xhtml

```
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
<h:head>
    <title>Dialogo Prueba</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="idFormTest">
        <h:panelGrid id="idPgAdressStore" columns="2" columnClasses="col1,col2">
        <h:outputLabel for="idAdress" value="Adress: " />  
        <p:inputText id="idAdress"  label="Adresss" size="40" value="#{storeBean.au.strAdress}"/>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:panelGrid width="100%" columns="2" style="text-align:center">
                <p:commandButton id="idBtSaveDir" value="Save" actionListener="#{storeBean.saveAdress}" />
                <p:commandButton id="idBtCancelDir" actionListener="#{storeBean.closeAdress}"  value="Cancel"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

this dialog is open of other form "idFormStore", when I click commandButton "idBtSaveDir" the method saveAdress is called and the value in idAdress is copied in other inputtext in idFormStore

```
public void saveAdress(ActionEvent event) {
    au.setAdressStore(au.getStrAdress());
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("idFormStore");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog("/pages/logistica/store/view_test");
}
```

I am updating the form idFormStore, but it doesn't update
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("idFormStore") doesn't work,

I also put the panelgrid where is the inputext and doesn't update, 
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("idFormStore:idPanelStore")

but I reload all the page the value that I enter appear, so What is that I have to put in RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dialog Framework opens the dialog in an iframe.
To update values in the parent view add this ajax event to the commandButton or commonadLink that opens the dialog:

```
<p:commandButton value="Open Dialog" actionListener"...">
   <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="idFormStore"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the update in xhmtl:

```
<p:commandButton id="idBtSaveDir" value="Save" ajax="true" update=":idFormTest" actionListener="#{storeBean.saveAdress}" />
```